# How to find distinct values that occur to right of the index i

Tags: python, arrays, list, indexing

Given

```
Arr=[7,7,3,2,3]
```

The number of distinct elements that occur to the right of index `i` will be

```
>>> [2,2,1,0,0]
```

Comment: Figure out how to do it for a single list. Then make a loop that calculates it for the slices starting at each index.

Comment: A more optimized way for long lists is to first use `collection.Counter()` to get all the counts. Then loop through the list, subtracting 1 from the count for that element, removing it entirely if it becomes zero. Then the value at that index is the number of keys in the dictionary.

Comment: I don't see how you get [2,2,1,0,0].  discinct element on the rights of the indexes should be [3,2,2,1,0] or, if you want to exclude the element at index i itself: [2,2,1,1,0].  On the other hand if you want to count elements on the right that are distinct from the element **Up to index i** then you should state that clearly.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the OP needs to show some effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from collections import Counter
from typing import List

ll: List = [7,7,3,2,3] #your list
idx: int = 3 # your index value


Counter(ll[:idx])
```

OUTPUT:

```
Counter(ll[:idx])
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the length of the set of elements in the array minus the element on the right of each index using a list comprehension on the range of indexes.

Solution based on your sample result:

```
[len(set(Arr)-set(Arr[:i+1])) for i in range(len(Arr))]

[2, 2, 1, 0, 0]
```

Solution based on your stated problem:

```
[len(set(Arr[i+1:])) for i in range(len(Arr))] 

[3, 2, 2, 1, 0]
```